# Not Sure how to setup this object association

Tags: model, ruby-on-rails-3.1, associations

Ok here's the layout. I've got a profile object which has a lot of other objects associated with it. I'm trying to allow my users to list past and present struggles in their profile. I have my base struggle object which just has a struggle field and then i have a battle object which is my lookup table so it contains a profile_id, struggle_id.

This is fine if all my struggles are the same but i need to figure out how to differentiate between a present and past struggle. I added a boolean to the battles table, but honestly i'm not sure how to make this all work the rails way. Do i create model objects for past and present which inherit struggle? how do i get my profile to see them?

thanks and i'll update with any code as directed by the community.

Running Rails 3.1

Answer (score 0):

Instead of a boolean in the join table trying use a Timestamp which can be NULL. If the Timestamp is NULL then you know they haven't overcome the struggle. If the timestamp is present, they have overcome the struggle AND you know when it was done.

Are you using (has_many :through => :struggles) or similar? You can do (has_many, :through => :struggles, :order => 'struggles.timestamp'). Not sure how you can access the join_table's attributes from the profile object -- but I hope this is a good start!

Comment: that's a good idea. We aren't really tracking when someone overcomes a struggle but that's an interesting spin for sure. i'm doing has_many :through => battles which is my lookup table. what i wanted to do was have something like has_many :past_struggles, :through => battles